# Select two sets of column based on row indices

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, subset

The working example is the best way to show what I'm looking for.

```
Given input df
df <- data.frame( l = letters[1:10], n = 1:10)
   l  n
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
4  d  4
5  e  5
6  f  6
7  g  7
8  h  8
9  i  9
10 j 10
```

I want to select rows from column l based on a vector of starting indices and a length. For example

```
start <- c(2, 4)
len <- 2
```

I want to get the output

```
b c
d e
```

I tried

```
df[(start):(start+len),1]
[1] b c d
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
Warning messages:
1: In (start):(start + len) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In (start):(start + len) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

Apply doesn't work either.

```
apply(start, 1, function(x, d) {d[x:(x+2),1]}, d = df)
Error in apply(start, 1, function(x, d) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` on 'start' to get the `seq`uence with `length.out` specified as 'len'.  Then either extract the 'l' as a `vector`

```
df$l[unlist(lapply(start, function(x) seq(x, length.out =len)))]
```

or as a `list` of `vector`s

```
lapply(start, function(x) as.character(df$l)[seq(x, length.out = len)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options to get the exact output you have specified, but first make sure your df$l is not a factor.

```
df <- data.frame(l = letters[1:10], n = 1:10, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
start <- c(2, 4)
len <- 2

for (s in start) {cat(df[s:(s+len-1), 1]); cat("\n")}
# b c
# d e

cat(sapply(start, function(x) {paste(df[x:(x+len-1), 1], collapse = " ")}), sep = "\n")
# b c
# d e
```